# Prove homeomorphism with equivalence relation

Tags: calculus, general-topology

This is an easy topology exercise that I can't figure out.

> Let ~ be an equivalence relation in **$\mathbb{R}^ 2$** such that $(x,y) \sim (x+1, 2y)$.
> Prove that **$\mathbb{R}^ 2/\sim$** is homeomorphic to $S^1\times\mathbb{R}$.

I'd be happy if someone explained to me what path I should follow (don't even know where to start, actually), thanks in advance :)

Comment: $$(x,y)\mapsto \left(e^{2\pi x i},y/2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\right)$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It would be good to explain the idea, though. I thought of this too but haven't yet found a clear way to communicate it to op

Comment: @ThomasAndrews how did you get to this?

Comment: If I had an answer, I'd have posted an answer, @FShrike I posted a comment because it seemed like a good start.

Comment: Roughly, you know $\Bbb R/(x\sim(x+1))\cong S^1$ (I hope). This is also easy to visualise. So you can tell something similar is going on here. In particular on the $\Bbb R\times\{0\}$ ($y=0$) that's exactly what the relation is. Then thinking about the $y$ coordinates, they double exactly when the integer part of the $x$ coordinate move across by $1$ and if you want to **pick a canonical representative** (which is a usual strategy), it's natural to look at $[0,1)\times\Bbb R$. Try to relate $(x,y)$ to some $(a,b)$ with $(a,b)\in[0,1)\times\Bbb R$

Comment: Essentially, $$(x,y)\sim \left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor,y/2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\right).$$ So $[0,1)\times\mathbb R$ is a system of distinct representatives of the quotient.